# Verb form used for sounds in Comics

Tags: verbs

What Esperanto verb form is used for sounds in comics when the sound cannot be described easily by spelling it out? An example is English *sigh*, German *seufz* (note the pure verb stem being used here, a verb form termed Erikative in honour of the German translator Erika Fuchs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s a very nice Esperanto translation of an Italian comic called Rat-Man. In that it seems to use the root word with an apostrophised ending. I guess that means it is using a noun instead of the verb. I think it works well and it sounds very similar to what you describe in German. For example:

> Suspir’
>
> Anhel’
>
> Paf’
>
> Fal’

[image: Examples from Rat-Man using words for sounds]