# How to say "bang" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, interjections

According to vortaro.net, it seems that [paf](http://vortaro.net/#paf) might be the answer but regargind the examples I'm unsure whether there might be some more specific word for the sound of a gunfire. Also, "La adventuro da Tinĉjo" uses it as well (althought it might not be correct).

Is "paf!" the best translation for "Bang!"?

Comment: See also this answer for an example of “paf’” being used in the comic Rat-Man. https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/5025/13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and it seems you can also use 'pif'. Precisely 'pif, paf!' is mentioned in [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/ekkrioj_sonimitoj/ordinaraj_radikoj.html) as a exclamation/interjection for gunfire and it references Zamenhofs translation of The Ugly Duckling by HC Andersen;

> “Pif, paf!” eksonis subite krakoj, kaj ambaŭ sovaĝaj anseroj falis senvive en la kanaron, kaj la akvo fariĝis ruĝa de sango.